# Ambiguous Out Joins Workaround?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a database with three tables.

Table 1:

> User_ID (primary key)
>
> First_Name

Table 2:

> User_ID
>
> Activity_Code
>
> Activity_Date

Table 3:

> Activity_Code (primary key)
>
> Activity_Desc

I want to pull User_ID, First_Name & Activity_Desc. The code I have is:

```
 SELECT  Table1.User_ID,  Table1.First_Name,  Table3.Activity_Desc
 
 FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN  (Table2 INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table3.Activity_Code =
 Table2.Activity_Code)  ON Table1.User_ID= Table3.Activity_Desc;
```

But, I am getting an error about an ambiguous outer join. Is there a way to use sub-query to get around this with out having to run two separate queries?

Comment: `ON Table1.User_ID= Table3.Activity_Desc` makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem to me you'd want two left joins:

```
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN (Table2 LEFT JOIN Table3 
ON Table2.[Activity_Code] = Table3.[Activity_Code]) ON Table1.User_ID =
Table2.User_ID
```

As long as you have referential integrity in place that should avoid the error.